# Create sitemap with both http and https protocol

Tags: asp.net, seo, sitemap

I have a problem with sitemap. My site use http/https protocols. When I try to generate sitemap using http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ and send any http link generated just first level links. 
For example I have two level pages: fist level- http://testserver/users which has a lot of link user profile. But all users profile link looks like  **https**://testserver/smith,
**https**://testserver/white etc

So generated sitemap looks like

```
<url>
    <loc>https://dtestserver/users</loc>
</url>
```

And no second level link was`t generated.

If I use this link **https**://testserver/smith, then sitemap contain all menu link with https, but not contains another user page links **https**://testserver/white

Why it happens?

Comment: I create just one file - without https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix http and https in XML sitemaps.

One solution e.g. A1 Sitemap Generator uses (in *default* config) is to alias and convert URLs with the non-root-protocol (say https) to the is-root-protocol (http)

So if root is http://example.com then https://example.com/test1.html becomes http://example.com/test1.html

But the overall rule is: You can not mix protocols in XML sitemaps

Answer (score 3):

can you simply ignore the protocol?

```
<loc>//dtestserver/users</loc>
```

Comment: I don`t know how google engine will work with it. Also it mean that I have to do all job manually. Create all links.

Comment: Google Search Console coplains - Sitemap can be read, but has errors, Invalid URL, 2011 instances, This is not a valid URL. Please correct it and resubmit.
...

The relevant lines in sitemap file:
 < loc > //www.example.com/ < / loc >
 < loc > //www.example.com/fr.html < / loc>